# Why have a "using namespace" and then "using namespace.class"

Tags: c#, namespaces

Sorry about bad title -- it's hard to explain in one sentence.

If a "using" statement allows us to use all of the code within a namespace, then why is there a need for `using Namespace;` then the same statement with the addition of a more qualified path, `using Namespace.Class`?

Here's what I mean:  let's say we have this:

```
using System;
namespace MyProgram 
{
     class Program 
     {
          static void Main() 
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Hi there");
               Console.Readline();
          }
     }
}
```

Obviously, we need the **System** namespace to use the Console class to print stuff to the screen.  Great.

Next, we need to create a **List**.  To do this, we have to put in the namespace-and-path-to-class to get access to the class that allows us to create a **List**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace MyProgram 
{
     class Program 
     {
          static void Main() 
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Hi there");
               var l = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
               Console.Readline();
          }
     }
}
```

Why do we have to add that new **using** statement?  If `using System;` allows us access to all of the code in the **System** namespace, and *System.Collections.Generic* is inside said **System** namespace, then wouldn't the `using System;` statement allow us access to it, making `using System.Collections.Generic;` redundant?

Comment: Re the title; that's not a class, it's another namespace. Re the query; using doesn't import hierarchically. I've VTC your question as "not reproducible" because it's based on an incorrect assumption

Comment: The full name of `List<T>` is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. You can write `var l = new `System.Collections.Generic.List<int>() { ... }`, or you can write `using System.Collections.Generic;` and then `var l = new List<int>() { ... }`. A `using <Namespace>;` only brings in the types in that namespace, and not in any namespaces which whose names just start with `<Namespace>`

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `Console` is a static type defined inside a `System` namespace. The `List` class is defined inside the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. You can only use types that are defined directly inside a namespace you are using, so to use the `Console` you need the `System` namespace but that doesn't include other types in the child namespaces.